# Wraping TextView When Text Goes Longer Then One Line

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, layout-gravity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<ProgressBar android:id="@+android:id/progress_small"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textSize="15sp"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:text="LOREM IPSUM BAB BABALOREM IPSUM BAB BABALOREM"
   />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

How to remove the Gap between L of Lorem and the progress bar ? I want text to be center aligned only.

textview width is wrap content. But there is gap on both the side.
How to get rid of that ?

Neither i am looking to single line it. as i don't want to miss any word it is showing.

Neither i am looking to left align it

Comment: I dont think you can achieve what you're aiming for on purpose, i think it comes down to how android wraps the words etc, adding a short word might push the first line more to the left. Thats at least whats happens on my S2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Setting the weight of progressBar to 1 and width to 0dp you can get desired result but cannot guarantee that it will work in all screen dimensions

EDIT:

With the above changes, I was able to get the desired output.

[image: Result of above changes]

Comment: Mani, ya it looked like what you just posted. But try reducing the length of the string and see that gap to become more prominent again.

Comment: The text length is dynamic

Answer (score 1):

In your textView make this changes ::

```
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="15sp"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:singleLine="True"  
          android:text="LOREM IPSUM BAB BABALOREM IPSUM BAB BABALOREM"/>
```

Comment: I don't want it to be single line. It should wrap to next line with center gravity

Comment: This is not what i am looking for :(

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
android:gravity="center|left"
```

Comment: So you want the first line, to be left-aligned/all to the left, and the second line should be center/still in the middle ?

Comment: no exactly. i want text to be centered but progressbar to touch near L of Lorem

Comment: would love a screenshot to see what you're aiming for

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/ProgressDisplay"
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ProgressDisplay"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="LOREM IPSUM BAB BABALOREM IPSUM BAB BABALOREM"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```